# Unknown character gets added in csv

Tags: csv, import, magento2

Unable to import product from csv having unknown character in some column.
http://prntscr.com/rbb6vg

Let me know the reason behind such character and how to resolve

Comment: Please attache csv file in your question.

Comment: You need to open the csv with a program set to show it in utf-8 encoding (the format default Magento saves it in). If it's still there in utf-8, check the data source, and use a converter.